# How do I access the store's information from within my custom module

Tags: magento2, admin, module

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */

     public function execute(){
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */


        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Queueapp_Queueapp::queueapp_auth');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Queueapp'));

        $this->setPageData();

        return $resultPage;
     }

     protected function setPageData(){
         // I want to access store data here e.g store name etc  
        // $store   = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $store = "me";

        return $store;
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by store info? Can you add more info please.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $storeFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory $storeFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->storeFactory = $storeFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */

     public function execute(){
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */


        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Queueapp_Queueapp::queueapp_auth');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Queueapp'));

        $this->setPageData();

        return $resultPage;
     }

     protected function setPageData(){
        $storeId   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $store = $this->storeFactory->create()->load($storeId);
        $name = $store->getName();
        //do what ever you need with $store or $name
        return $store;
     }
}
```